# MongoDB Saving Sub Document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I m newbie mongo and node.js.I m using MongoDB and I working on Todo list app.

https://github.com/ishuah91/Nodejs-MongoDb-TodoMVC

This is my todo model

```
  function init(Schema, mongoose){
   var TheSchema = new Schema({
   title: String,
  complete: Boolean
 });

 return mongoose.model('Todos', TheSchema);
 }

  module.exports.init = init;
```

But I want to do this model will be saved as in other document like sub-documemt.

```
    var mainDoc = Schema({
      name:String,
      author: String,
      receiver: String,
     list: [TheSchema]
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to do the following :

```
var mainDoc = Schema({
   name:String,
   author: String,
   receiver: String,
   list: {
          title: String,
          complete: Boolean
         }
});
```

Comment: yes I know this . but I dont want to break the example.I only want to give  list and the other elemet saved as sub document.